# Outer minimum vectorization in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

Given an NxM matrix A, I want to efficiently obtain the NxMxN tensor whose ith layer is the application of np.minimum between A and the ith row of A. Using a for loop:

```
> A = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5,6]])
> output = np.zeros(shape=(A.shape[0], A.shape[1], A.shape[0]))
> for i in range(a.shape[0]):
      output[:, :, i] = np.minimum(A, A[i])
> output
array([[[1., 1., 1.],
        [2., 2., 2.]],

       [[1., 3., 3.],
        [2., 4., 4.]],

       [[1., 3., 5.],
        [2., 4., 6.]]])
```

This is very slow so I would like to get rid of the for loop and vectorize it. I feel like there should be a general method that works with any function of a matrix and a vector not just, minimum. Using np.minimum.outer does not work as it outputs an order 4 tensor.

Answer (score 1):

With `broadcasting` we can make a (3,3,2) result:

```
In [153]: np.minimum(A[:,None,:],A[None,:,:])
Out[153]: 
array([[[1, 2],
        [1, 2],
        [1, 2]],

       [[1, 2],
        [3, 4],
        [3, 4]],

       [[1, 2],
        [3, 4],
        [5, 6]]])
```

and then switch the last 2 dimensions to get the (3,2,3) you want:

```
In [154]: np.minimum(A[:,None,:],A[None,:,:]).transpose(0,2,1)
Out[154]: 
array([[[1, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 2]],

       [[1, 3, 3],
        [2, 4, 4]],

       [[1, 3, 5],
        [2, 4, 6]]])
```

Or do the transpose first

```
In [155]: np.minimum(A[:,:,None],A.T[None,:,:])  # (3,2,1) (1,2,3)=>(3,2,3)
Out[155]: 
array([[[1, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 2]],

       [[1, 3, 3],
        [2, 4, 4]],

       [[1, 3, 5],
        [2, 4, 6]]])
```

### edit

Adding the sum is trivial:

```
In [157]: np.minimum(A[:,:,None],A.T[None,:,:]).sum(axis=1)
Out[157]: 
array([[ 3,  3,  3],
       [ 3,  7,  7],
       [ 3,  7, 11]])
```

Comment: This works, but weirdly does not improve performance in my use case

Comment: I actually want to compute the sum along the smaller axis of the resulting tensor, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74679407/outer-minimum-vectorization-in-numpy-follow-up)

Comment: In this test case the iteration size is only 3!