# Outer minimum vectorization in numpy follow up

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

This is a follow-up to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74678481/outer-minimum-vectorization-in-numpy/74679017#74679017).

Given an NxM matrix A, I want to efficiently obtain the NxN matrix whose ith row is the sum along the 2nd axis of the result of applying `np.minimum` between A and the ith row of A.

Using a for loop,

```
> A = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5,6]])
> output = np.zeros(shape=(A.shape[0], A.shape[0]))
> for i in range(A.shape[0]):
      output[i] = np.sum(np.minimum(A, A[i]), axis=1)
> output
array([[ 3.,  3.,  3.],
       [ 3.,  7.,  7.],
       [ 3.,  7., 11.]])
```

Is is possible to optimize this further without the for loop?

Edit: I would also like to do it without allocating an MxMxN tensor because of memory constraints.

Answer (score 0):

instead of a for loop. Using the NumPy minimum and sum functions, you can compute the desired matrix output as follows:

```
output = np.sum(np.minimum(A[:, None], A), axis=2)
```

Comment: This works but in my test it actually appears slightly slower than the for loop. Aditionally, it requires me to allocate an MxMxN tensor which makes my machine run out of memory with the data I am working with

Comment: With very large arrays, iteration on one of the smaller dimensions can be faster.  Memory management gets more complicated with large (broadcasted) arrays.